# how can i check all the values of dataframe whether have null values in them without a loop

Tags: python, pandas

`if all(data_Window['CI']!=np.nan):`

I have used the `all()` function with `if` so that if column `CI` has no NA values, then it will do some operation. But i got syntax error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC, you want to check that there are no null values in your dataframe. You can call:

```
df.notnull().values.all()
```

Comment: Great! Remember to upvote and choose the best answer when you get a chance!

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
dataframe.isnull().values.any()
```

Comment: This returns `True` if there are any null values in your dataframe, and `False` otherwise. My command `dataframe.notnull().values.all()` returns the opposite, i.e. True if all values are not null, and False otherwise. Just want to make sure OP knows.

Answer (score 0):

This gives you all a columns and how many null values they have.

`df = pd.DataFrame({0:[1,2,None,],1:[2,3,None])`
`df.isnull().sum()`